# Why is there no "update all plugins" in the shopware 6 backend?

Tags: plugins, command-line-interface, backend, shopware6

I'm managing multiple shopware 6 shops with a lot of plugins installed. The backend only allows to update one plugin which is quite time consuming because the updates done in 2 steps:

- the update is loaded (loader circle)
- the backend is relaoded (html reload)

why is there no "update all plugins" button (like e.g. in wordpress ;-) )?

best,
Roman

I'm expecting an gui or a cli command which allows to download and update all plugins with pending updates at once.

Answer (score 6):

Not excactly what you're asking for but you can pass multiple names to the cli command:

`./bin/console plugin:update PluginName1 PluginName2 -n`

You can also pass an empty string like this and it will update all plugins:

`./bin/console plugin:update "" -n`

The `-n` will skip the interaction to confirm the update for the given plugins.

To do that the plugins have to be present in the new version you want to have. I'd recommend to use composer to manage the plugins. Shopware has it's own registry where you can get all plugins via composer. You can find the configuration in your Shopware account. After you've bought a plugin you'll get a bearer token and can require your plugins like this:

`composer require store.shopware.com/pluginname`

So you will still have two steps to get the plugin and afterwards update it, but it's much more convenient than doing it in the administration.

Edit: Added the `-n` flag as suggested by tinect below.

Comment: Additionally, adding `-n` as argument to the `plugin:update` command will prevent any need of confirmation